# Rails ActionController::Parameters sanitize

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, strong-parameters

I need to sanitize the strong parameters in Rails5 in Rails 4 I used this:

```
 def forest_hash(hash)
        new_hash = hash.deep_dup
        new_hash.each do |k, v|
          new_hash[k] =
            if v.is_a?(Hash)
              forest_hash(v)
            # elsif v.respond_to?(:to_unsafe_h) 
            #   forest_hash(v.to_unsafe_h)
            elsif v.is_a?(String) && DATE_TIME_REGEXP === v
              v = Time.zone.parse(v)
            elsif v == ''
              nil
            elsif v == ['']
              []
            elsif v == '<p>&nbsp;</p>'
              nil
            elsif v == 'true'
              true
            elsif v == 'false'
              false
            elsif v.is_a?(String) && v.to_i.to_s == v
              v.to_i
            elsif v.is_a?(Array) && v.count > 1
              v.delete_if { |x| x == '' }
            elsif v.is_a?(String) && base_helpers.strip_tags(v) != v
              Foresttrees::TagSanitizer.new(v).sanitize
            elsif v.is_a?(String)
              v.squish
            else
              v
            end
          if new_hash[k].is_a?(Array) && new_hash[k].all? { |vv| vv.is_a?(Hash) }
            binding.pry
            new_hash[k].map! { |vv| forest_hash(vv) }
          end
        end
      end



<ActionController::Parameters {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"XXXXXXX", "commit"=>"Save", "activism_tree"=><ActionController::Parameters {"name"=>"qewrqewr", "reason"=>"", "affected_locations"=>["", "global"], "risk"=>"3", "description"=>"<p>qerqewr</p>", "published_at"=>"", "published_internet_at"=>"", "related_tree_ids"=>[""], "target_customer_ids"=>["", "5f75952427e4984019f6e9d4"], "monitored_source"=>"false", "cuter"=>"qerqewrqewr", "cut_duration"=>"", "expected_date"=>"", "cut_probability"=>"", "place"=>"", "hour"=>"", "followers"=>"0", "simplified_evidences_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"qerqewrq", "description"=>"", "type"=>"url", "url"=>"qwerqwer", "sanitized"=>"false"}}} permitted: false>, "type"=>"activism", "controller"=>"foresttrees/trees", "action"=>"create", "locale"=>"en"} permitted: false>
```

The problem is that:

after doing that `params.each {​​ |k,v| params[k] = v }​​.class`
I get a hash so I loose the permit, required methods,
I tried to use slice and fetch but slice is not really working properly. And I want not loose de ActionController::Parameter Properties in my new object.

so how I can proceed

Answer (score 0):

Thera are many difference between Rails 4 and Rails 5 and one is in Strong parameters:

> But with Rails 5, ActionController::Parameters will no longer inherit
> from HashWithIndifferentAccess

As [pointed here](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/07/25/parameters-no-longer-inherit-from-hash-with-indifferent-access-in-rails-5.html)

But if you look at [the documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0.7/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-transform_values), you can use other methods that can perform better your task more functionally, without the deep_dup and without using map! and work excusively in the values of the object that you want in this case.
in this case you should use transform_values also alternatively exists with !.

One thing important is that v can be a scalar (String, number ...), Array or Hash or another (ActiveController::Parameters). so you can process like this:

```
  def forest_hash(hash)
        hash.transform_values do |v|
          if v.is_a?(Hash) || v.is_a?(ActionController::Parameters)
            forest_hash(v)
          elsif v.is_a?(String) && DATE_TIME_REGEXP === v
            Time.zone.parse(v)
          elsif v == ''
            nil
          elsif v == ['']
            []
          elsif v == '<p>&nbsp;</p>'
            nil
          elsif v == 'true'
            true
          elsif v == 'false'
            false
          elsif v.is_a?(String) && v.to_i.to_s == v
            v.to_i
          elsif v.is_a?(Array)
            v.delete_if { |x| x == '' }.map do |vv|
              vv.is_a?(Hash) || vv.is_a?(ActionController::Parameters) ? forest_hash(vv) : vv
            end
          elsif v.is_a?(String) && base_helpers.strip_tags(v) != v
            Foresttrees::TagSanitizer.new(v).sanitize
          elsif v.is_a?(String)
            v.squish
          else
            v
          end
        end
      end
```

You should also, maybe encapsulate some value manipulation the scalar String and Array (hash ActiveController::Parameters always recursive) in a separate method, to made this code more ruby like and no need of the infinite if else chain.

Whith this code you return a new ActionController::Parameters that applies the sanitazions or modifications on the values